# Python getopt module error "NameError: name 'opts' is not defined" after importing

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, nameerror, getopt

I'm trying to take in two arguments from the console. **The following code seems to have worked on my colleague's computer**, so I'm not sure why it is giving me an error when trying to run it on mine. I am on a Mac.

```
import getopt
import sys
    
   
question_id= None
arg_student = None
argv = sys.argv[1:]
print("test")

try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "i:s:", ["question_id=","arg_student="])
except:
    print("Error")

for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ['-i', '--question_id']:
        question_id = arg
    elif opt in ['-s', '--arg_student']:
        arg_student = arg

print("Question Number: " + question_id)        
print("Student response: " + arg_student)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
   Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ailanysmacbook/github/AutomatedEssayGrading/AutomatedEssayGrading/input.py", line 1, in <module>
    import getopt
  File "/Users/ailanysmacbook/github/AutomatedEssayGrading/AutomatedEssayGrading/getopt.py", line 20, in <module>
    for opt, arg in opts:
NameError: name 'opts' is not defined
```

It seems to be happening right after I try importing it. Do I need to install something? I'm not sure what's missing.

This is what I'm putting into the console:

```
python3 input.py -i 0 -s Sample text.
```

Comment: The line where `opts` would be defined raises an exception (which you hide by printing a meaningless "Error"), so it is not defined. Remove the try/except to see what the real problem is (obviously keep the line `opts, args = ...`)

Comment: Yes, I understand it's not defined, the first error occurs at line 1 when importing getopt.

Comment: remove try catch block and define `opts, args = getopt.getopt(...)` to see whats happening first.

Comment: I removed the catch block and its still giving the same error

Comment: Also delete or rename your file named getopt.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

I had another file called getopt.py in the same folder which was overriding the default python module. Renaming it to input.py fixed this issue.